# Simple (newbie) accordion effect with headings and paragraphs

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion, nodes

I need to know how to create a simple accordion effect when an h2 heading is clicked (only the h2 tags that are under the div with an id of "accordion").  The paragraphs under the headings should display if they are hidden or hide if they are showing when the heading is clicked.  The directions for the assignment are in the HTML code.  I am about 90% there but I need help seeing what I am doing wrong.  This is a complete newbie script so I can't use anything that complicated (no innerHTML).  I need to be able to get to the parentNode of the h2 heading (which has a div tag) and use the parentNode to get to the paragraph children that are under the h2 headings.  So I am going to paste my HTML, CSS and JavaScript below.  One more final note, I can't alter the CSS or the HTML, the accordion has to work based on the JavaScript.  The JavaScript must have 2 functions and only 2 functions.  Ok, here's the code:

**HTML**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Best Practices - Jason McCoy</title>
        <link href="css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Accordion - Jason McCoy</h1>
        <hr />
        <h2>Instructions</h2>
        <p>Create a simple accordion while implementing best practices.</p>
        <ol>
          <li>Change the part of the page heading to your name.</li>
          <li>Add your name to the &lt;title&gt; also.</li>
          <li>Create and link to an external CSS.
          <ul>
            <li>Create a class with a single declaration: <em>display:none;</em> Name the class <strong>.hideContent</strong>.  No class attribute should be added to the HTML.</li>
            <li>Create a second class with a single declaration: <em>display:block;</em> Name the class <strong>.showContent</strong>.</li>
            <li>Create two more CSS rules. One should remove the bottom margin from all H2s. The other should remove the top margin from all paragraphs.</li>
          </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Create and link to a JavaScript file.
          <ul>
          <li>Create exactly two functions. One called <strong>preparePage()</strong> that automatically applies the .hideContent style to all paragraphs within the accordion div and then makes the desired H2s call the second function when clicked. The second function,<strong>accordion()</strong>, performs the class switching.</li>
          <li>Make preparePage() run when the page loads.</li>
          <li>When an H2 inside the "accordion" div is clicked, the associated paragraph should change class so that it appears. If the paragraph is already visible, then it should disappear when its H2 is clicked.</li>
          <li>No inline JavaScript should appear in the HTML. Only a SCRIPT tag should be present in the HTML. No other JavaScript should be in the HTML anywhere.</li>
          <li>Study the HTML first so you know the structure! Similar to backing up out of folders (like you did in NOS-110 using subdirectory markers) you will have to &quot;back up&quot; out of the H2 to get its parentNode. Then you can use that parentNode to descend back down to the child paragraph.</li>
          </ul>
          </li>
        </ol>
        <p>The only changes to this HTML file should be the addition of a &lt;script&gt; tag to link to your JS file, the addition of a &lt;link&gt; tag to link to your CSS, and the addition of your name to both the title and page heading.</p>
        <div id="accordion">
        <div>
        <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
        <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and   typesetting industry..</p>
        </div>
        <div>
        <h2>Where does it come from?</h2>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text..</p>
        </div>
        <div>
        <h2>Why do we use it?</h2>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
        <h2>Where can I get some?</h2>
        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* create a class that hides the text */
.hidecontent {
display: none;
}

/* create a class that shows the text */
.showcontent {
display: block;
}

/* h2 rules */
h2 {
margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* paragraph rules */
p {
margin-top: 0;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
/* once the page finishes loading, run the preparePage function */
window.onload = function preparePage() {

/* Step 1: get the necessary elements needed from the accordion div section of the HTML */
    var accodion = document.getElementById('accordion');                    
var accordionHeadings = accordion.getElementsByTagName('h2');               
var accordionParagraphs = accordion.getElementsByTagName('p');                      

/* Step 2: use a for loop to set the class of the accordionParagraphs to 'hidecontent' */
for (var i = 0; i < accordionParagraphs.length; i++) {                  
    accordionParagraphs[i].className = 'hidecontent';               
}

/* Step 3: use a for loop to get to the headings
 * when a heading is clicked,
 * run the accordion function
 */
    for(var i = 0; i < accordionHeadings.length; i++) {
        accordionHeadings[i].onclick = function accordion() {
            if(accordionParagraphs.className == 'hidecontent') {
                accordionParagraphs.className = 'showcontent';
            } else {
                accordionParagraphs.className = 'hidecontent';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that, in step 3, you try to set the `className` of `accordionParagraphs`, which is actually an array rather than an element.

Try replacing it with something like this:

```
accordionHeadings[i].onclick = function accordion() {

    // 'this' refers to the element that was clicked
    // 'nextElementSibling' gets the element directly after it
    var accParagraph = this.nextElementSibling;

    // now you have the right element, you can change its class
    if (accParagraph.className == 'hidecontent') {
        accParagraph.className = 'showcontent';
    } else {
        accParagraph.className = 'hidecontent';
    }
}
```

Edit:

You could also do it like this:

```
// 'this' refers to the element that was clicked (heading)
// 'parentNode' gets its parent
// 'getElementsByTagName('p')[0]' selects the first <p> element
var accParagraph = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!  Works perfectly!!  Do you know how you would do it this way? Instruction: Back out of the H2 to get its parentNode. Then you can use that parentNode to descend back down to the child paragraph.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That works perfectly as well. You da man!!  I am very new to JavaScript but I enjoy it and I have learned a lot by coming to stackoverflow thanks to awesome people like you.

Answer (score 0):

Nicely written question, first off.
Using two functions eh? There's a few different ways to do this. 
You have already assigned the onclicks, so you're in good shape. But you're assigning the *accordeonParagraphs* array itself a class name, not the element. Careful there. Use accordionParagraphs[i].className...

Basically, you need to first find the index of the clicked header. That's easy enough, because an onclick event registers with the window object- get the targetd object by using window.event.target (might vary from browser to browser so look up how to do it thoroughly if your assignment depends on it- this works in chrome and FF for sure).
Using that, you have an actual reference to the object that was just clicked. Since you already have a list of your headers, run through them and see which one is the one you clicked:

```
for(var i = 0; i < accordeonHeadings.length; i++){
    if(window.event.target == accordeonHeadings[i]){

    }
}
```

Now inside that if statement, you simply use the index of i to access the respective paragraph and change it.

```
for(var i = 0; i < accordeonHeadings.length; i++){
    if(window.event.target == accordeonHeadings[i]){
        if(accordionParagraphs[i].className == 'hidecontent') {
            accordionParagraphs[i].className = 'showcontent';
        } else {
            accordionParagraphs[i].className = 'hidecontent';
        }
    }
}
```

That should do it. I didn't test this code, it may contain typos that will break it so test it out yourself.

Good luck brother.